# Example of series of the form $\sum \frac{1}{n^{1+a_n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How one can find a sequence $(a_n)$ of positive numbers such that $\lim a_n=0$ and

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=i} \frac{1}{n^{1+a_n}}$$

converges.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Notice htat $\sum \frac{1}{n\log^2 n}$ converges. 
So, make this happen by setting 
$$n^{a_n}=\log^2 n,$$
Then $a_n\log n = 2\log\log n.$

Answer (score 1):

If the $a_n$ decrease slow enough to make $\frac1{n^{1+a_n}}$ non-increasing, the the series converges by the Cauchy condensatoin test, provided
$$ \sum_n 2^n\cdot\frac 1{2^{n(1+a_{2^n})}}=\sum_n \frac 1{2^{na_{2^n}}} $$
converges. If we try to make
$$ \frac 1{2^{na_{2^n}}}=\frac1{n^2},$$
we are led to $a_{2^n}=\frac2n\log_2n$ and generalize this to $a_n=\frac{2}{\log_2n}\log_2\log_2n$. Remains to show that this makes $\frac1{n^{1+a_n}}$ non-decreasing ...

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$ a_{n} = \frac{\log \log n}{\log n} + \frac{2 \log \log \log n}{\log n} $$

for large $n$. Then

$$\frac{1}{n^{1+ a_{n}}} = \frac{1}{n \log n (\log \log n)^{2}} $$

for large $n$ and by the integral test, the corresponding summation converges.